# How to verify the validity of docker images build from docker-compose?

Tags: docker, testing, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I am trying to come up with a CI system where I validate the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yaml files that are used to build our images.

I found Google [containter-structure-tests](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/container-structure-test) 
that can be used to verify the structre of Docker images that are built. This works if the docker images are build from Dockerfile.

Is there a way that I can verify the docker images with all the configurations that are added to the images by Docker-compose?

EDIT: 
Maybe I didn't all put all my details into the questions.

Lets say I have docker-compose file with the following structure:

```
version: "3"
services:
  image-a:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-a
  image-b:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-b
      ports:
          - '8983:8983'
      volumes:
         - '${DEV_ENV_ROOT}/solr/cores:/var/data/solr'
         - '${DEV_ENV_SOLR_ROOT}/nginx:/var/lib/nginx'
```

Now that the images would be built from Dockerfile-a and Dockerfile-b, there would be configurations made on top of image foo-b. How can I validate those configurations without building the container from image foo-b? Would that even be possible?

Comment: What do you mean by build from docker-compose ? In the end even docker-compose needs a Dockerfile to build so you have a Dockerfile anyway :D

Comment: 'those configurations' do you mean the files from the docker volumes?

Comment: @Thomasleveil . Yes. Configurations such as volumes, ports, etc.

Comment: Volumes' content is not available in _docker images_. You can access volume content only from running _containers_. So container-structure-test is useless for that use case

Comment: @Thomasleveil: Exactly my question here. If I want to test the validity of the volume, are there any frameworks that I could make use of?

Comment: Where is the added value of bothering with docker if the goal is to validate files located in a directory on the host system (`${DEV_ENV_ROOT}/solr/cores` and `${DEV_ENV_SOLR_ROOT}/nginx`)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  image-a:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-a
  image-b:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-b
```

Build your images running the command `docker-compose --project-name foo build`. This will make all images' name start with the prefix `foo_`. So you would end up with the following image names:

- foo_image-a
- foo_image-b

The trick is to use a unique id (such as your CI job id) instead of `foo` so you can identify the very images that were just built.

Now that you know the names of your images, you can use:

- `container-structure-test test --image foo_image-a --config config.yaml`
- `container-structure-test test --image foo_image-b --config config.yaml`

If you are to make some kind of generic job which does not know the docker compose service names, you can use the following command to get the list of images starting with that `foo_` prefix:

```sh
docker image list --filter "reference=foo_*"
```

> ```
> REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
> foo_image-a         latest              0c5e1cf8c1dc        16 minutes ago      4.15MB
> foo_image-b         latest              d4e384157afb        16 minutes ago      4.15MB
> ```

and if you want a script to iterate over this result, add the `--quiet` option to obtain just the images' id:

```sh
docker image list --filter "reference=foo_*" --quiet
```

> ```
> 0c5e1cf8c1dc
> d4e384157afb
> ```

Comment: Maybe I didnt all put all my details into the questions.